# How to get Rows updated automatically?

Tags: iphone, three20, ttthumbsviewcontroller

HI all,

I have made my custom Data Model, custom Data Source and a TTTableViewController which uses my data source, now in data model there we are mentaining the array, if something changes in the datamodel, ui should auto reflect those change, how this thing can be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can send the -reloadData message to the UITableView. Also, there are methods in UITableView to insert/delete particular rows. This also can give you nice animations. Please take a look at the "[Table view programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1)" for details.

Comment: I want partial loading, only those rows should be affected, which are being updated. Also this is in context of TTTableViewController, a class from Three20 library.

Comment: BTW, i have done it by defining custom DataModel which populates the data source and notify the UI class to update object by object.